# Pass Variable From HREF to Google HTMLSERVICE App

Tags: javascript, url, google-apps-script

I have built a rather useful tool for my work place that allows me to keep track of employee attendance. My latest addition is, when an infraction is flagged an email goes out with a link to that infractions ID. I want to be able to click that link, load the html page and pass the infraction ID to the page. I have been doing a lot of searching, but can't seem to find a clear answer, nor a case that closely resembles mine. The accepted answers I have found don't seem to apply to my situation.

Here is the example:

```
URL: https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycomp.com/s/blahblahmyID/dev

HREF: https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycomp.com/s/blahblahmyID/dev?cID=1457989239035-cc3050b8
```

I want to pass the `1457989239035-cc3050b8` value to my page. Once I get that on the page I can handle it from there, just can't find a way to pull it from a HREF link in an email. One of the drawbacks of not using a traditional website.

Here is my `doGet()` code to load the `Index.html` from the app:

```
 function doGet(e) {

 return HtmlService
     .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
     .evaluate()
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }
```

Not sure how useful that code is though as it is pretty standard. Am I pretty out of luck trying to do this?

UPDATE:

I realized that I haven't given enough information on how this system works. I am using HTML to serve information stored on spreadsheets (google sheets). The ID in question is a reference to an entry in the spreadsheet (column 1). It isn't a part of the app, I am just looking to pass the value of the `row` I need to get data from. If I have this value I can run a script to get all the other values from the spreadsheet.

Comment: the ID is an attribute of the e.parameter object, you should get it using something like `id=e.parameter.id`

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the `e.parameter` object works and how I pass it to that object from a `<a href=''></a>` provided in an email.

Comment: you pass it just as you show it in your question , right after the question mark in the url :HREF: .......(http removed for readability)...script.google.com/a/macros/mycomp.com/s/blahblahmyID/dev?cID=1457989239035-cc3050b8

Comment: So once the page loads the `e.parameter` can see that value? If I have my `doGet()` returning the `Index.html` how can I also pass that value? I guess I am not quite seeing the picture just yet.

Comment: the .gs code will get it when doGet is executed, in the same doGet function you should store this value to make it available to another function. You will have to run a client side function on page load that will retrieve this value from the server code using the aforementioned function. Maybe I should write this in an answer with an example if you want ?

Comment: I see and that makes sense. So say I declare variable `var myVal` and in the `doGet(e)` I assign the `myVal` to `e.parameter` that will pull the value? If you could write it out I would greatly appreciate it. I am very visual.

Comment: see answer below ;-)

Comment: I just spent 3 days writing a big script that plays tennis like that between server and client side... I'm beginning to get familiar with it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is an attribute of the e.parameter object, you should get it using something like `id=e.parameter.id`

You can pass it just as you show it in your question , right after the question mark in the url

`HREF:https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycomp.com/s/blahblahmyID/exec?id=1457989239035-cc3050b8`

The server code will get the value, store it somewhere and be ready to send it back when the client javaScript asks for it.

See shematic example below:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var id = e.parameter.id
 PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('id',id);
 return HtmlService
     .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
     .evaluate()
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }
function returnID(){
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('id');
}

// in your client javascript, add a call like this (outside of any function so it is executed on page load... or use onload="theFunctionName"...):

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getID).returnID();
function getID(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: The `setProperties(string,string)` came back with an error saying that it was not a method, but I found a work around! Thank you! This is going to make my apps MUCH more useful in the future. :-)

Comment: Yes, that was a typo... It is setProperty in this case, I updated a few minutes later but you took it already ! Thx for accepting.